# TableView With An Embedded ListView

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx, java-8

I'm trying to make a `TableView` with an embedded `ListView`, but I'm not exactly sure what to do, I've been researching how to embed Buttons into a `TableColumn` and I've seen that I should create a custom class that extends `TableColumn` and overrides `updateItem()`.
I have a:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<FoodModel, ObservableSet<Food>> storeFood;
```

for the tableColumn, set by the FXML editor. It's value is set by `this.storeFood.setCellValueFactory(val -> val.getValue().getFood);` and `this.storeFood.setCellFactory(value -> new ListViewCell<>());` upon initialization.
I've been encountering a problem in which the list on screen is not being populated. Can I have a checklist of things to do to embed a list into a `TableColumn`?

Cell:

```
private static final class ListViewCell<T, V> extends TableCell<T, V> {

    private ListView<T> list;

    ListViewCell() {
        this.list = new ListView<>();
        this.list.setPrefHeight(60);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(V item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty) {
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            setGraphic(this.list);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, your code fragment does not contain any attempt to populate the list so the question is rather why you expect the list to be populated.

Comment: @Holger Isn't the `setCellValueFactory` with the reference to the `ObservableSet<Food>` supposed to set the values?

Comment: Sure. It does so by delegating to the `updateItem` method of the cell. Since *you* are the one who implements the cell, *you* are the one who has to populate the `ListView` *you* have created. In the end, JavaFX has to know how to get from a cell’s single item to the populated `ListView` you want to see and writing the code which will do it is the typical way to tell a software system how to do it.

Comment: @Holger Oh! Now it makes sense! I added an `add` call in the `updateItem` and it works!